# What's wrong with my batch code?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a save system for my text based rpg game (which is just for fun, won't turn out to be anything), but it just wont save. I've made a smaller code that includes this problem.

```
@echo off
color a
title TestSave
set /a physdam=3
cd C:\Users\%username%\Documents
mkdir testsave2>nul
echo set /a physdam=%physdam%>save.bat
echo Process Complete!
pause>nul
```

The output i get when i run this batch program is this;

> set /a physdam=
>
> Process Complete!

help

Edit: It also won't create a save.bat inside the testsave2 folder.

Comment: Please change your question title to something more soecific! The current title does not help other users searching for a solution of a similar problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you add space before `>save.bat`, but I am not sure why the file is created blank without the space. Also, `>save.bat` will create the file in the current directory which was `C:\Users\%username%\Documents`. You can either `cd testsave2` or specify the path like `>testsave2\save.bat`

```
@echo off
color a
title TestSave
set /a physdam=3
cd %USERPROFILE%\Documents
if not exist testsave2 mkdir testsave2 > nul
echo set /a physdam=%physdam% > testsave2\save.bat
echo Process Complete!
pause > nul
```

If you want to avoid the error message when the folder testsave2 exists, you can check for it with `if not exist testsave2`.

To see the values for all of the  environment variables like `%USERNAME%` and `%USERPROFILE%`, you can use the `set` command without anything after it.

Comment: While it's neat that you've provided the packaged code, your answer would be much better if you explained what this code changes and how it solves the problem, so that future users don't have to use a diff tool and educated guesses to figure out the solution.

Comment: Ryan is right. Although it's obvious to "us old batch guys", I don't think, OP can figure out, *why*  your's work and his doesn't (and I really hope he cares).

Comment: You guys are absolutely right, and the question was "What's wrong with my batch code?" after all. I will update my answer with some information.

Comment: See [this site](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for a deeper explanation. OP's code tries to redirect stream 3 to the file, but `echo` doesn't print anything to stream 3, so the file remains empty. Run the code with `echo on` to watch, what exactly happens. (quite surprising, if you are not aware of how redirection works)

Comment: Ah, i see .. it will interpret `3>` before the echo

Comment: thank you all so much, i've looked around a bit more and did found out the problem was that there wasn't a space before ">". thanks. altough i am a bit confused because this only has a problem with numbers, like 1 2 3. but if i tried to save a word for example `set /a foo=fooo`, and then used `echo foo=%foo%>save.bat` this would work.

Comment: Yes, 0 to 9 are used for numeric handles, but it will be ok with `10>` or `-1>`

Comment: the downside of the space is, that it is part of the string, which may or may not make a difference. There are two common tricks to avoid the space: `(echo foo3)>file` and `>file echo foo3`